# Mootools insert a BR after every X characters

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have a string: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs."

I want to use mootools to insert a /br  ONCE at 40 characters.

Comment: Your title is contradicting your question.

Comment: O>O Why do you want to port it to MooTools if you can have it in native code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mBMDZ/**

If you want to add a `<br />` after the first 40 characters, use:

```
var string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.";
string = string.replace(/^([\S\s]{40})/, "$1<br />");
$("elementID").innerHTML = string;
```

If you want to add a `<br />` after every 40 characters, use:

```
string = string.replace(/([\S\s]{40})(?=\S)/g, "$1<br />");
```

Comment: this may be ok for vanilla js but using `$("someid").directproperty = value` is not the mootools way - it will break in 2.0 when $ becomes wrapped and does not return the element. `$("someid").set("html", value);` etc etc

Comment: this actually *isn't working correctly, check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mBMDZ/

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I got to work, "insert" a br tag ONCE at 40 characters.

```
      var string = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs.";
      string = string.replace(/(.{40})/g,"$1<br />")

      $("element").innerHTML = string;
```

Heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mBMDZ/1/